# Open modern POP window using dropdownlist in ASP.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, popup

I have wright a code for open a modern pop window in asp.net that code is working good. but i also want to open pop window using select a data from deopdown list. here is a code which i have wright for open pop window when user click on button but how can i open pop using select Item from dropdonwn list that pop up says Upgrade Membership.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddWeek" class="contact-input" runat="server" Width="400px"
        AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddWeek_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList>

      <div id="modal">
    <div id="headingpop2">
        Select You Plane for Upgrade Membership
    </div>
     <div id="contentpop2">
        <p>Select you plan as per you like to Upgrade</p>
        <a runat="server"  href="Becomeamember.aspx"
            class="buttonpop green close" style="margin-top: 140px; margin-right:     
       230px;">
            <img src="images/tick.png">Upgrade Now</a> <a style="margin-top: 140px; 
             margin-right: 50px;"
                href="#" class="buttonpop red close">
             <img src="images/cross.png">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#button1').click(function (e) { // Button which will activate our modal
                $('#modal').reveal({ // The item which will be opened with reveal
                    animation: 'fade',      // fade, fadeAndPop, none
                    animationspeed: 600,  // how fast animtions are
                    closeonbackgroundclick: true, // if you click background 
                     // will modal close?
                    dismissmodalclass: 'close' // the class of a button or 
                   //element that will close an open modal
                });
                return false;
            });
        });    
    </script>
```

This code is working with Button but i want it will work with dropdownlist too. any one have a any idea how can i do this please help me out.

Thank You

Comment: Could just attach a similar button handler to the .change() event on your select list?

Comment: I tried that but not working